# MySQL date conversion("30-Jan-2013" to "2013-01-28")

Tags: mysql, sql, date, formatting

In my page (PHP), I have date format like this: "30-Jan-2013". I want to convert this format to "2013-01-28".

Is it possible in MySQL date format?

Comment: That's a rather unusual format, if the 30th January is indicated by "28"

Answer (score 1):

use `STR_TO_DATE` to convert string to date

```
SELECT DATE(STR_TO_DATE(colName, '%d-%b-%Y'))   -- date datatype
```

or

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(colName, '%d-%b-%Y'),'%Y-m-%d')  -- string type
```